# Setting return value for a python function with a function

Tags: python

Why does this python return statement NOT work?

```
def f():
    return ['The world needs more engineers', 'I need a raise', ]

def g():
    x = []

    return x.extend(f())

a = g()
print a
```

The return value for "a" is None.  Why?

Comment: Because you have to read the documentation. Who told you that `extend` would return something *different* than `None`?

Comment: Because `extend` returns None.

Comment: Questions like this make me wish there were a way to close with a link to the [reference docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), or [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list) for things that are explained repeatedly by Python itself and don't need to be explained again on SO…

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `None` because this line in function `g`:

```
return x.extend(f())
```

returns the result of using `list.extend` on `x`.

`list.extend` operates in-place.  Meaning, it always returns `None` and thus should be on its own line.

---

To fix the problem, make your code like this:

```
def f():
    return ['The world needs more engineers', 'I need a raise', ]

def g():
    x = []
    x.extend(f()) # Use list.extend on its own line
    return x

a = g()
print a
```

Output:

```
['The world needs more engineers', 'I need a raise']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I pulled the trigger on the question too early.  I did exactly what you suggested.

Comment: @MichaelBartz - Happy to have helped!  Please don't forget to [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) though.  Doing so helps keep SO organized.

Answer (score 1):

> The return value for "a" is None. Why?

Because that's what the [`list.extend`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method returns.

Almost all methods in Python that mutate a value in-place return `None`. So, you want either this:

```
x.extend(f())
return x
```

(mutate the value, then return it)

… or this:

```
return x + f()
```

(create and return a new value)

---

If you're wondering *why* Python was designed this way, it's explained [in the FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list). It talks about `list.sort`, but the same logic is true for other cases. (Note that, just as `sort` has a companion new-list-creating function `sorted`, `extend` has a companion new-list-creating operator `+`. This isn't always true, but even when it isn't, the mutating method will return `None`.)